# Prevent duplicate entries in a join table in a many-to-many relationship in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

I'm using EclipseLink 2.5.1 (and Hibernate 4.3.5 final). Given the following tables in MySQL.

- product
- prod_colour (join table)
- colour

There is a many-to-many relationship between products and their colours.

A product can have many colours and a colour can in turn be associated with many products. This relationship is expressed in the database by these tables.

The `prod_colour` table has two reference columns `prod_id` and `colour_id` from its related parent tables `product` and `colour` respectively.

As obvious, the entity class `Product` has a list of colours - `java.util.List<Colour>` which is named `colourList`.

The entity class `Colour` has a list of products - `java.util.List<Product>` which is named `productList`.

---

The relationship in the `Colour` entity :

```java
public class Colour implements Serializable {

    @JoinTable(name = "prod_colour", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "colour_id", referencedColumnName = "prod_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "prod_id", referencedColumnName = "colour_id")})
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "colourList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Product> productList; //Getter and setter.

    //---Utility methods---

    //Add rows to the prod_colour table.
    public void addToProduct(Product product) {
        this.getProductList().add(product);
        product.getColourList().add(this);
    }

    //Delete rows from the prod_colour table.
    public void removeFromProduct(Product product) {
        this.getProductList().remove(product);
        product.getColourList().remove(this);
    }
}
```

The relationship in the `Product` entity :

```java
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @JoinTable(name = "prod_colour", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "prod_id", referencedColumnName = "prod_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "colour_id", referencedColumnName = "colour_id")})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Colour> colourList; //Getter and setter.
}
```

From the associated EJB, the insert operation is performed as follows.

```java
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean insert(List<Colour> colours, Product product)
{
    int i=0;
    Long prodId=product.getProdId();
    for(Colour colour:colours)
    {
        Product p = entityManager.getReference(Product.class, prodId);
        colour.addToProduct(p);

        if(++i%49==0)
        {
            entityManager.flush();
        }
        entityManager.merge(colour);
        entityManager.merge(p);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Everything works fine.

---

When duplicate rows are attempted (same `Colour` entities associated with the same `Product` entity), they are also inserted into the `prod_colour` table that I expect should not happen.

Do I need to perform some extra conditional checks to avoid duplicate insertion or EclipseLink/Hibernate have some mechanism to prevent duplicates in such situations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's also surprising for me. I always was thinking that it made reference columns in join table as composite primary key, but it does not. If you want to have unique records try use `Set` instead of `List` or create your own ManyToMany relationship table with composite primary key(color_id, product_id). I don't have better idea.

Comment: Thank you. Earlier I was using `java.util.Set`s but I replaced them with `java.util.List`s because `Set`s have their own limitations I came across somewhere. In case of using `Set`s, yes it does insert duplicate rows as being happened in this case. Using a composite primary key is, many a times not recommended.

Comment: Why this is not recommended? I prefer using my own relation table in many to many relationship. Why? If your chief tell you 'i want to know number of product with that colour' where you put this information? product_colour table is the best place. And you have much more control when you define own relationship table.

Comment: I have changed this relationship to use `java.util.Set` to prevent duplicate insert into the `prod_colour` table.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a uniqueConstraints on the JoinTable as shown below:

```
@JoinTable(name = "prod_colour", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "prod_id", referencedColumnName = "prod_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "colour_id", referencedColumnName = "colour_id")}, uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
                            "colour_id", "prod_id" }))
```

This will prevent duplication of entries when a direct sql is being executed directly against the table and via your application code.